# Disable actions, move, resize, minimize, etc using python-xlib

Tags: python, xlib

I'm making a program where I need to lock the position of a window on the screen, one would think the easy way to do this is using _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS but apparently didn't work or I don't know how it work xD... I tried to send an event, something like this:

```
def getatom (atom):
    return self.display.intern_atom(atom)

data = [getatom("_NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE"),getatom("_NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE"),
        getatom("_NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW"),getatom("_NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP"),
        getatom("_NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE")]
state = getatom("_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS")
event = Xlib.protocol.event.ClientMessage(window = window, client_type = state, data = (32, data))
root.send_event(event, X.SubstructureRedirectMask)
self.display.sync()
```

That did nothing, if I use xprop the allowed actions are _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP and _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE but I can still move the window, I really don't know how to do this/how it work, if someone can clarify me this and give me an example would be much apreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question, but I had a similar problem, so, here's what I ended up using: the Motif-compatible, unofficial, yet supported by most window managers `_MOTIF_WM_HINTS`. The definitions are from the old Motif code (should be in `Xm/MwmUtil.h`), but everybody is cloning them, so:

```
struct MwmHints {
    unsigned long flags;
    unsigned long functions;
    unsigned long decorations;
    long input_mode;
    unsigned long status;
};
enum {
    MWM_HINTS_FUNCTIONS = (1L << 0),
    MWM_HINTS_DECORATIONS =  (1L << 1),

    MWM_FUNC_ALL = (1L << 0),
    MWM_FUNC_RESIZE = (1L << 1),
    MWM_FUNC_MOVE = (1L << 2),
    MWM_FUNC_MINIMIZE = (1L << 3),
    MWM_FUNC_MAXIMIZE = (1L << 4),
    MWM_FUNC_CLOSE = (1L << 5)
};
```

And the code would be something like this:

```
struct MwmHints hints;
Atom wm = XInternAtom(display, "_MOTIF_WM_HINTS", False);
hints.functions = MWM_FUNC_RESIZE | MWM_FUNC_MINIMIZE | MWM_FUNC_MAXIMIZE | MWM_FUNC_CLOSE;
hints.flags = MWM_HINTS_FUNCTIONS;
XChangeProperty(display, window, wm, XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char*)&hints, 5);
```

Since we left out `MWM_FUNC_MOVE`, the windows should be unmovable.

In my (limited) testing, these mostly work, except `MWM_FUNC_RESIZE`, which mostly doesn't.

Porting these to Python shouldn't be hard, but I didn't need this in Python and I prefer to share working code.

Answer (score 2):

`_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS` don't seem to be about what you want at all:

> The Window Manager MUST keep this property updated to reflect the actions which are currently "active" or "sensitive" for a window [...]  Window Managers SHOULD ignore the value of _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS when they initially manage a window. This value may be left over from a previous Window Manager with different policies.

Among freedesktop extensions, `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE` comes closest to what you want: specify certain window type to *recommend* certain behavior. No chance, though, to get an *exact* thing you want (like, unmovable window with decorations), and no guarantee that WM would obey this hint at all.

You might want to use `OverrideRedirect` attribute: when it's set before a window is mapped, WM does not intervene into window mapping process. It means no decorations, no reparenting and no user-originating actions with that window: you promise to manage it by yourself. It *will* be unmovable (unless *you* provide a facility of dragging it around). It will also (perhaps unfortunately) be undecorated.

Comment: Thanks, I really need to read better the documentation... I don't really care about the decoration meanwhile my app is running, I tried to set the window type as a notification and it did what I wanted but when I change the type back to normal X was unresponsive for some reason xD... Ill try to remap the window and manage it myself, I think that is the way to go...

Comment: Actually, OverrideRedirect is also just a flag wich WM can ignore (none of non-experimental managers ignote it though afaik)