# How to tell the X window manager to remove maximize button on the titlebar?

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I'm programming in C with libX11 (aka Xlib), but I am confused about how to disable the maximize button?

I think that libX11 is **ONLY** a X Window System protocol client library, so can it tell the X window manager to disable one of the buttons or even add a new kind of button on the titlebar?

[image]

Comment: To be clear, you still want to be able to resize the window manually? Even resize it to the size of the screen?

Comment: @Dave Oh... I want the window like the dialogue above. No maximize button and to be unresizable. :-)

Comment: That's easier then; set the min and max size to the same values.

Comment: Where to set the min and max size? I wrote the code in C from scratch! No toolkit (Qt or GTK+) was used! BTW, how to make the maximize button disappear?

Comment: According to this page http://www.linuxmisc.com/18-writing-Linux-applications/603bb7b0ccd56d6d.htm you send the sizes as hints to the window manager via `XAllocWMHints`

Comment: See the [Extended Window Manager Hints Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.5.html)

Comment: This page looks like it is a good reference: http://www.hpc.unimelb.edu.au/nec/g1ae02e/chap14.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308603/preventing-window-maximisation-minimisation-in-x-window-system

Comment: Haha, I think I should use a widget toolkit right now. :-)